# Cannot run any BrowserStack tests through Robot Framework despite the backend running

Tags: testing, robotframework, browserstack

So I'm trying to run even an example test case from BrowserStack documentation through `browserstack-sdk robot ./tests/LocalTest.robot` but all I'm getting is a:

`[browserstack_sdk.__init__][CRITICAL] - Encountered error while setting up - Could not start Browserstack Local: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>`

The backend is running properly - when I run the binary provided by my company, it runs fine, the web dashboard is accessible. When I set up the corporate proxy in the dashboard, the connection to any of our environments results in a 200 so everything should be fine. As for running any tests though - all I'm getting is the error above :( Tried playing with the `browserstack.yml` file in the example suite I'd like to run but regardless of the options I set (proxy, forceLocal, trying to use localIdentifier), it's still the very same error.

What may be causing this if the backend seems to be working fine?

Comment: Please try this repo https://github.com/browserstack/robot-browserstack/tree/sdk with SDK

If that does not helps please raise ticket with support@browserstack.com